# How can I change from a function call to now use function (e, arg) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have been using the following code:

```
        $("input[id^='Order_'], input[id^='Default_']")
        .change(function (e) {
            var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
            updateField('Menu', $(this), type);
        });
```

But now I started to use a widget and this has the following kind of code:

```
        $("input[id^='Order_']")
            .wijinputmask({
                mask: '0-0-0-00',
                hidePromptOnLeave: true,
                textChanged: function (e, arg)
            })
```

How can I change from what I had before where it just calls the updateField function to this new kind of format where it says function (e, arg). Should I put my call to updateField inside the function (e,arg)?

From what I see in the documentation:

```
e: The jQuery.Event object.
args: The data with this event.
args.text: This is the new text.
```

Answer (score 1):

As the input will have a mask functionnality, I suppose you have to use the plugin's "textChanged" instead of the *native* change event:

```
$("input[id^='Order_']").wijinputmask({
    mask: '0-0-0-00',
    hidePromptOnLeave: true,
    textChanged: function(e, arg) {
        var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
        updateField('Menu', $(this), type);
    }
})​
```

I've never used this plugin so I'm not 100% sure that "this" is the input field in the "textChanged" event callback. In case it is not, you can normally use "e.target".